# Adding the Frequency to each Words Respectively (Java)

Tags: java, file, frequency

My program does not  show any error messages(like runtime errors) but I am  pretty much dealing with a logic error. So the thing is that this program is supposed to  count the frequency of  each word in a file but it is not.

The output I am getting from this program is the frequency of (1) for each words. For example my file contains the word "and" like 10 times but this program displays that the frequency of "and" is (1) when it's not.

I'd really appreciate any feedback!

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class FrequencyOfWords {

     static int frequency[] = new int[999];
     static String words[] = new String[999];

     static int count_Word = 0;
     static int individual_Count = 0;

     public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {

         methodForInputtingWords();
         methodForPrintingOutWords();

     }

    public static void methodForInputtingWords() throws Exception {

    File file = new File("file.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

         String x;

         while (input.hasNext()) {

             x = input.next();
             words[count_Word] = x;
             count_Word = count_Word + 1;

             if (count_Word == individual_Count) {
                 words[count_Word] = x;
                 individual_Count = individual_Count + 1;

             } else {

                 frequency[count_Word] = frequency[count_Word] + 1;

             }

         }

    }

     public static void methodForPrintingOutWords() {

         for (int k = 0; k < count_Word; k++) {

             System.out.printf(" %10d %5s", frequency[k], words[k]);
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: Quite frankly, I cannot see how this counts words. Have you even stepped through the program? Can you elaborate on your logic? Btw, there is a ton of solutions to building a frequency map, which are a lot easier and use, a, well, map. If you're unsure how to make one, just use one of the existing algos.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `HashMap<String, Integer>` to store words and frequencies where `key` is a word and `value` is frequency of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are putting each word into a new field in the word array without checking if it is already in there.

A simple solution could be the already mentioned Hashtable with the words as key and an in as value.

```
if(wordHashTable.containsKey(word))
{
  //increase value for this key
}
else
{
  // add new key with count 1
}
```

Comment: Does the ArrayList class perform the same function as the HashMap class? I apologize for my limited understanding of Java.

Comment: No. The ArreyList is used to store objects without a relation to other objects while a HashMap stores pairs of Object to Object relations.
The ArreyList is like a real world written down list. On word a line.
The HashMap is a dictionary: a topic(key) and its explanation(value)